# Architecture of player hand in JavaScript card game

Tags: javascript, architecture, refactoring

So, i'm attempting simple card game. I have `player` "class" with `draw` function, and public members `deck` and `hand`, both are Arrays.

I need to draw a card from the deck, put it in hand and show it in player "hand" area. I'm concerned about the way I do "flip" and "play" buttons (through closures).

Here is the code:

```
littlegame.player.prototype.draw = function() {
    if (this.canDrawCard()) {
        var card = this.deck.draw(); // this.deck is Array

        //Create card element on the playfield

        var card_object = $('<div class="card"></div>').append($('<span class="attack">' + card.attack + '</span>')).append($('<span class="defence">' + card.defence + '</span>'));

        // Add controls to card
        if (this.playerid == 1) {
            var flipper = $('<span class="flip">Flip</span>');
            flipper.click(function(){
                card.flip();
            });

            var actuator = $('<span class="play">Play</span>');
            console.log('Loading actuator closure with id ' + this.playerid + ' and name ' + this.playername);
            var player = this;

            var old_hand = this.hand.slice(0); // Store a copy of old hand. Stupid trick, i know. It doesn't work

            actuator.click(function(){
                card.play(player.playerid);
                delete card;
                player.hand = old_hand;
            });

            card_object = card_object.append(flipper).append(actuator);
        }

        this.element.append(card_object);
        card.element = card_object;

        // Put card in hand
        this.hand.push(card);
    }
};
```

What i need is a way to call `card.play()` and `card.flip()` on corresponding button presses, with `card.play` knowing card position in hand, to remove the card. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
littlegame.player.prototype.draw = function() {
        if (this.canDrawCard()) {
                var card = this.deck.draw(); // this.deck is Array

                //Create card element on the playfield

                var card_object = $('<div class="card"></div>').append($('<span class="attack">' + card.attack + '</span>')).append($('<span class="defence">' + card.defence + '</span>'));

                // Add controls to card
                if (this.playerid == 1) {
                        var flipper = $('<span class="flip">Flip</span>');
                        flipper.click(function(){
                                card.flip();
                        });

                        var actuator = $('<span class="play">Play</span>');
                        console.log('Loading actuator closure with id ' + this.playerid + ' and name ' + this.playername);
                        var player = this;

                        var old_hand = this.hand.slice(0); // Store a copy of old hand. Stupid trick, i know. It doesn't work

                        actuator.click(function(){
                                card.play(player.playerid);
                                delete card;
                                player.hand = old_hand;
                        });

                        card_object = card_object.append(flipper).append(actuator);
                }

                this.element.append(card_object);
                card.element = card_object;

                // Put card in hand
                this.hand.push(card);
                var hand = this.hand;
                card.remove = function () {
                     var i;
                     for(i=0;i<hand.length;i++) {
                       if(hand[i]===this) {
                           hand.splice(i,1);
                       }
                     }
                }
        }
};
```

The key here is to define the remove function in the scope that contains the variables you're interested in. Here, I define the variable `hand`, which makes it available inside the remove function that I define immediately after. You can then call the remove function whenever you like.
If you know that the card will not change position within the hand, you can shortcut by making the index some variable (say, `cardposition`) and simply splice your array there, or whatever it is you want to do with your array.

Comment: Hmmm. If, let's say, I splice third card from hand, won't remaining cards shift by 1 to beginning?

`card.delete` is cool, I'll try it now.

Comment: yes, but since I don't have your design document on hand, and I don't know what card game you're playing, I had to kind of guess at what you want.

Comment: Actually, I have no design document :) The issue was storing persistent links to objects in array so they doesn't stop working when array elements get deleted.

Anyway, seems that your approach actually works well. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following. I had to leave position of card in hand array in the closure along with links to player and the card itself. It goes like this:

```
littlegame.player.prototype.draw = function() {
    if (this.hand.length < this.agility) {
        var card = this.deck.draw();

        // Put card in hand
        this.hand.push(card);

        var card_in_hand = this.hand[this.hand.length - 1];
        var card_position = this.hand.length;

        //Create card element on the playfield
        var card_object = $('<div class="card"></div>').append($('<span class="attack">' + card.attack + '</span>')).append($('<span class="defence">' + card.defence + '</span>'));

        // Add controls to card
        if (this.playerid == 1) {
            var flipper = $('<span class="flip">Flip</span>');
            flipper.click(function(){
                card_in_hand.flip();
            });

            var actuator = $('<span class="play">Play</span>');
            console.log('Loading actuator closure with id ' + this.playerid + ' and name ' + this.playername);
            var player = this;

            actuator.click(function(){
                card_in_hand.play(player.playerid);
                player.hand.remove(card_position);
            });

            card_object = card_object.append(flipper).append(actuator);
        }


        this.element.append(card_object);
        card_in_hand.element = card_object;
    }
};
```

I also used `Array.remove()` [function](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-array-remove/) from John Resig.

Comment: Ooh, no luck. Cards sometimes just stay in hand :( Why, oh why JavaScript arrays is not like PHP arrays?